# Bool doesn't contain a definition for "Any" and no extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am just starting with ASP.NET MVC Core.

Everything goes well until now, and when I want to parse some data to Book model it look like that can not recognize an `Any` method and `FirstOrDefault`.

My code is below.  Any help ?

```
public string GetDeweyIndex(int id)
{
    if (_context.Books.Any(book => book.Id == id))
    {
        return _context.Books
                       .FirstOrDefault(book => book.id == id).DeweyIndex;
    }
    else 
        return "";
}
```

**Book Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LibaryData.Models
{
    public class Book : LibaryAsset
    {
        [Required]
        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DeweyIndex { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**LibaryContent**

```
public class LibaryContext : DbContext    {

        public LibaryContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Patron> Patrons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Checkout> Checkouts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CheckoutHistory> CheckOutHistories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LibaryBranch> LibaryBrances { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BranchHours> BranchHours { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LibaryCard> LibaryCards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LibaryAsset> LibaryAssets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Hold> Holds { get; set; }
        public bool Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I get this kind of error

> Error CS1061
>   'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   LibaryServices
>   C:\Users\Demir\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Libary-Managment-System\LibaryServices\LibaryAssetsService.cs
>
> Error CS1061
>   'bool' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   LibaryServices
>   C:\Users\Demir\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Libary-Managment-System\LibaryServices\LibaryAssetsService.cs   57  Active

Comment: Can you include the definition of `Books` on the `_context` object?

Comment: The error suggests that what you're calling `.Any` / `.FirstOrDefault` on, `_context.Books`, is a `bool`. It shouldn't be, it should be something like a `DbSet<Book>`. Can you show how it is defined?

Comment: Of course, I possted book.cs model

Comment: `public bool Books { get; set; }` -- Yeah, that explains the error. Is this a typo of some sort or did you really want something other than `DbSet<Book>` here?

Comment: thank you @hvd 
I didnt see this stupid error in my model. 
Now works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move from the comments to an answer:

The error message is saying

> *'bool'* does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Emphasis mine. This makes sense, a `bool` is just `true` or `false`, it does not hold any items.

You've shown the definition of `Books`:

```
public bool Books { get; set; }
```

This should have type `DbSet<Book>`, similar to how all the other properties in your context are defined.

(I'm going to make a guess: I suspect you started with `DbSet<`, started typing `boo`, had your IDE auto-complete it to `bool` rather than `Book`, got an error because `DbSet<bool>` isn't allowed, and fixed that error the wrong way. Even if this guess is incorrect in your case, I've seen similar things happen before, so it may serve as a hint for others who do make that mistake and can't figure out why they wrote what they did.)